# Java program of returning alphabets that a word is made of

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to understand how pieces of code are contributing the program in java. So the program is supposed to take input from user for a word and then the output is printing the alphabets that the user inputted word is made of. The program is running fine but I need help in interpreting what the for loops are doing. Thank you!

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class J0307_search {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1;
        int count;
        char[] arr1=new char[40];

        Scanner s=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("input a string:");
        str1=s.nextLine();
        arr1[0]=str1.charAt(0);
        System.out.print(arr1[0]+"");


        for (int i=1; i<str1.length();i++) {
            count=0;
            for (int j=0;j<i;j++) {
                if (str1.charAt(i)==str1.charAt(j)) {
                    count++;

                }
            }
            if (count<1) {
                arr1[i]=str1.charAt(i);
                System.out.print(arr1[i]+"");
            }
        }
        System.out.print(" : only made up of these alphabets");
        s.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a way too complicated solution for such a simple problem. I would suggest making a HashSet.

Comment: Way to complicated for a pretty straight-forward task. Why not just iterate over the `char[]` that contains the string entered by the user?

Answer (score 2):

I change code and add explain.

```
    boolean behindExist;
    for (int i=1; i<str1.length(); i++) {//loop for all character in string
        behindExist = false;
        for (int j=0; j < i; j++) {
            //check same character is exist before now char 
            //Ex) if (i = 3), check
            //str1.charAt(3) == str1.charAt(0);
            //str1.charAt(3) == str1.charAt(1);
            //str1.charAt(3) == str1.charAt(2);
            if (str1.charAt(i)==str1.charAt(j)) {
                behindExist = true;
            }
        }

        if (!behindExist) {//if not behindExist
            arr1[i]=str1.charAt(i);//add to arr1
            System.out.print(arr1[i]+"");//and print character
        }
    }
```

And, this is my code.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("input a string : ");
    String input = sc.nextLine();

    for(int charCode : input.chars().distinct().toArray()) {
        System.out.print((char)charCode);
    }
    System.out.print(" : only made up of these alphabets");
    sc.close();
```

Short. I love it. I hope this can be help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Can we use something as simple as this? The Set will contain unique characters that make up the word.

```
char[] charArr = str1.toCharArray();
Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet();
for(char c: charArr){
    charSet.add(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to complex the problem.

Try to use features of collection in java.

something like this:-

```
Set<Character> set = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(str1.toCharArray()));
```